# Pivot table from 4 different tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have four tables with 2 columns each in that one column name common "Workflow"
tb1

```
Workflow    |   progress
-----------------------
export data |   3
```

t2

```
Workflow    |   closed
----------------------
import data |    4
```

t3

```
Workflow    |   Finished
----------------------
extra data  |   2
```

t4

```
Workflow    |   notyet
----------------------
Oracle tags |   7
```

Now I am looking a result as follows,

```
Workflow   |  Progress   | Closed  |  Finished   |  notyet  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
export data |  3         | 0       |  0          |  0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
import data |  0         | 4       |  0          |  0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
extra data  |  0         | 0       |  2          |  0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle tags |  0         | 0       |  0          |  7       |
```

Comment: Any type id's colums for joining tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach of doing this would be

```
select * from 
(
    select workflow, progress, 0 as closed, 0 as finished, 0 as notyet from tb1
    union all
    select workflow, 0, closed, 0,0 from tb2
    union all
    select workflow, 0, 0, finished, 0 from tb3
    union all
    select workflow, 0, 0, 0, notyet from tb4
) t1
```

If you need grouped result then:

```
select 
  workflow, 
  sum(progress) as progress, 
  sum(closed) as closed, 
  sum(finished) as finished, sum(notyet) as notyet 
from 
(
    select workflow, progress, 0 as closed, 0 as finished, 0 as notyet from tb1
    union all
    select workflow, 0, closed, 0,0 from tb2
    union all
    select workflow, 0, 0, finished, 0 from tb3
    union all
    select workflow, 0, 0, 0, notyet from tb4
) t1 
group by workflow;
```